# UITableViewController in UINavigationController to represent tree structure of unknown depth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am pretty new to iOS.  I have some data that is essentially a tree structure which is fetched from an external database so its depth is not defined at compile time for the app.  I would like to display this information using UITableViewControllers inside of a UINavigationController. At this stage, I have embedded a UITableViewController in a UINavigationController in my storyboard, and have written a subclass of UITableViewController to display the first level of the tree. How do I programmatically segue to a new instance of the subclass of UITableViewController that I have created while also creating references for prototype cells I have defined in the storyboard.  Is it possible to set up this kind of structure in iOS with UITableViewControllers and a UINavigationController?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TableView delegate, put some code into the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to create a new instance of your tableViewController subclass.  Either pass it whatever data it needs to populate its cells, or possibly use your top level TableView delegate/datasource as the delegate/datasource for every new instance (you will have to keep track of where in your data hierarchy).  You can then use `self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:` to transition to the new tableViewController.  If you use the same subclass at each level, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method will use the same cell reuse identifier (unless you code otherwise), so your prototype cells should be used at every level.

Comment: Thanks.  That has worked well.  I had to redefine my prototype cells in the subclass, but everything else worked fine.